# magento 1.8.0.0: System -> Manage Currency -> Symbols: Page Not Found!

Tags: error, configuration, currency, bug

I've performed a search for "magento" "currency symbol" but did not find anything related to the problem I am having. Basically, I installed the XAMPP BitNami version of Magento on Windows 7, and most things tried so far work, but when I go to

System -> Manage Currecny -> Symbols

I get the following:

> Whoops, our bad...
>
> The page you requested was not found, and we have a fine guess why.
>
> If you typed the URL directly, please make sure the spelling is correct.
>     If you clicked on a link to get here, the link is outdated.

Any idea what is causing this?

Comment: Try to logout and login. Second: don't run magento on windows. it is pain in the...

Comment: Hi. I tried your suggestion but am still getting the error message. My installation is a standard XAMPP BitNami installation on Windows 7. Since I need to use Adobe Illustrator and Photoshop for my design work I need Magento working properly on Windows 7 which I am using as a staging platform. Please help.

Comment: Did you check the Debug-Tutorial and followed it? http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/429/217 Sounds like a problem with the htaccess, but windows is a plattform I have no idea of

Comment: Thank you for the pointer. I went through the list but was not able to resolve the problem. My installation is a plain vanilla installation, no custom theme, no modified php modules, just standard BitNami installation. Others should be experiencing the same problem as well. (?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error occurs with the definition of the admin router. It appears not only to be a windows error as I am also getting this on a linux machine. Currently it looks as follows:

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <currencysymbol>Mage_CurrencySymbol_Adminhtml</currencysymbol>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

But if you use the "before" tag and specify "Mage_Adminhtml" then it will work.

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <currencysymbol before="Mage_Adminhtml">Mage_CurrencySymbol_Adminhtml</currencysymbol>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

You should also add the dependency to the /app/etc/modules/Mage_CurrencySymbol.xml

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mage_CurrencySymbol>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>core</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Adminhtml />
                <Mage_Widget/>
            </depends>
        </Mage_CurrencySymbol>
    </modules>
</config>
```

There appears to have been a bug/fix raised on [github](https://github.com/magento/bugathon_march_2013/commit/41bffaef075de3e7ffee2d9354fb8ffe098f6b4d)

Comment: The bugfix on github also seems to say you also need to add a line to MageCurrencySymbol.xml . I've made both changes and it seems to be working now. Thanks.

Comment: Yes ideally you should make both changes so the dependency is added. I will update my answer.

Comment: Is it fine to directly change config.xml file in core to resolve this issue? because, we are not sure if Magento is going to resolve this issue in its next release and on next update the fix done by us will be overwritten.